# converting an arraylist(integer) to an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I've tried couple of things to make this code work, but it didn't.
my goal is to instantiate `nums[]` with numbers `{0, 1, 2, .... n-1}`. `nums` has no size, so I used list that instantiate `nums` with zeros. Keep in mind that the result must be an array (`nums`).

```
int nums[] = {}; int n = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number:");
n = scanner.nextInt();

ArrayList<Integer> listNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
nums = new int[listNum.size()];//instantiate nums with zeros 
//nums = listNum.toArray(nums);
for (int i =0; i < n; i++){
    nums[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Why not create `nums` after you ask the value for `n` ? The size will be known at that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're writing this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> listNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
nums = new int[listNum.size()];//instantiate nums with zeros
```

`listnum` has a size of 0, so `nums` won't be initialized as you want.

---

Why not just do :

```
nums = new int[n];
```

?

Comment: thank you very much, but it means that I don't need to create **arraylist** . I just want to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Array's are fixed in size.

```
 nums = new int[listNum.size()];
```

That never works. You are initializing your array with zero elements. Once you declare the array size, you can't change that back.

What you are looking for is

```
    int nums[] = {}; int n = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number:");
    n = scanner.nextInt();
    nums = new int[n];//instantiate nums with entered size
    for (int i =0; i < n; i++){
        nums[i] = i;
    }
```

Just get rid of that ArrayList since you are know the size `n`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an `ArrayList` - if you take the input of `n` from the command line, you could just use it to initialize the array:

```java
nums = new int[n];         
for (int i =0; i < n; i++){
    nums[i] = i;
}
```